# SELECT MAX values for duplicate values in another column

Tags: sql, db2

I am having some trouble finding an answer for this one, so I apologize if it was somewhere else.

I have a table 'dbo.MileageImport' that has the following layout which I pulled to find duplicate entries:

```
    |KEY      | DATA    |
    ---------------------
    |V9864653 | 180288  |
    |V9864653 | 22189   |
    |V9864811 | 11464   |
    |V9864811 | 12688   |
```

What I am having troubles with is when I run the following SQL in a DB2 environment:

```
    SELECT KEY, MIN(DATA)
    FROM dbo.MileageImport
    GROUP BY KEY
    HAVING (COUNT(KEY)>1);
```

It ends up pulling the following data:

```
    |KEY      | DATA    |
    ---------------------
    |V9864811 | 11464   |
    |V9864653 | 180288   |
```

For some reason it's pulling the MIN value for V9864811, but not V9864653. If I inverse that and put MAX instead of MIN, it pulls the opposite values.

Is there something I am missing here so I can pull the MIN DATA value for only duplicate KEY records, or is there another way to do this? The report where this data comes from changes from month to month, so there could be different keys that end up being duplicated that I need to correct. Ultimately I am turning this into a DELETE statement to delete the lower of the two (or more) duplicated mileage entries.

Comment: Is your data column char/varchar, or a numeric type?

Comment: My guess is that `DATA` column is of type VARCHAR not NUMBER. In this case `180288` is less than `22189` and MIN picks the former value, because the database treats these values as strings, not numbers (string begining with `1.....` is less than string beginning with `2...`)

Comment: Ahh, you two got it, I was working with a CHAR Column, I didn't think to double check that before posting thinking it was a numeric... I knew it was going to be something simple I overlooked. Thank you for helping to point out my miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your DATA column numerical? or a VARCHAR?

If you find its better to change it to a number if you can, maybe an integer if you aren't having any fractions and its just round numbers.

if not, then you could cast them to an integer value, but if there are lots of transactions or its a big table it will be slow and not ideal. Its bad practise to do that if you could just change the datatype!

```
SELECT KEY, MIN(CAST(DATA as Int))
    FROM dbo.MileageImport
    GROUP BY KEY
    HAVING (COUNT(KEY)>1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to change the datatype of the column, but its a relatively small table so the CAST worked perfect! Thank you for the code adjustment!

Comment: Be aware, if an alpha character sneaks into this column, your cast will fail.